# setInterval only runs once when trying to run a function that loops through querySelectorAll array

Tags: javascript, animation, for-loop, setinterval

I'm new to javascript, so I may lack basic understanding, but I don't understand why there is a problem in this code.

I'm trying to create a "console typing effect" which basically means that the a selected text should look like it's typed in "real time" after the page is loaded. I know that there are similar effects out there, but I want to do this in vanilla JS (no frameworks).

What I have done so far it (pseudo code):

1. Get elements with .console-effect Class end store them in "elementList"
2. Loop through the elements and add a cursor at the end of the text they have.
3. (here i failed :() Make the cursor blink

while debugging i found that in that after looping through the cursors(to make them blink) once, the method "elem.style.opacity" says that the element it has is "undefined"...

```
document.body.onload = function() {

    function addCursor(element) {
        // Create a Span with the cursor character and give it an class of .cursor
        var newSpan = document.createElement('span'),
            newSpanText = document.createTextNode('|');
        newSpan.appendChild(newSpanText);
        newSpan.className = 'cursor';

        //Add newSpan to the element var(passed trough the function)
        element.appendChild(newSpan);
    }

    function animateCursor() {
        var cursors = document.querySelectorAll('.cursor');

        for (var i = 0; i < cursors.length; i++) {
            cursors[i].style.opacity = '0';
            setTimeout(function() {
                cursors[i].style.opacity = '1';
            }, 500 );
        }
    }

    setInterval('animateCursor()', 1000);

    var elementsList = document.querySelectorAll('.console-effect');
    for (var i = 0; i < elementsList.length ; i++) {
        addCursor(elementsList[i]);
    }

};
```

Comment: This is classic `closure-in-loop` case. [Creating closures in loops: A common mistake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops_A_common_mistake)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your function called in Timeout does not know about your cursor:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  cursors[i].style.opacity = '1';
}, 500 );
```

something like this should work:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  this.style.opacity = '1';
}.bind(cursors[i]), 500 );
```

even if I'm sure you will find some explainations, let me know if you need help.
Btw: Lambda Ninja is right about passing a function as string- you should change that

Comment: Ok, i understand,  should it work if i do something like "setTimeout(function(cursors[i]) {..." too? and if it does, which is better?

Comment: this wont work, the argument will be undefined. "bind()" will execute the function in the scope of the first argument, storing all other arguments internally and pass them as an argument when executing. Using "this" will be the internal reference to the scope = 1st argument. So what you can do is choose any scope you want and pass the cursor as argument, e.g. function(cursor) { .. }.bind({}, cursons[i]) .. this way it's bound to an empty object and "this" will be {} (does not make any sense- just an example)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `()` from the `animateCursor()` in the `setInterval()`.

I.e., like so:

```
setInterval(animateCursor, 1000);
```

The parentheses make the function run immediately; putting it without the parentheses actually passes it as a parameter variable to `setInterval()`.

Comment: "The parentheses make the function run immediately". The OP wrap it into apostrophes so it is an expression.

Comment: Ok, thanks, i have a question, even if i put a console.log in there, and i wrap it with apostrophes it still runs, shouldn't it think it is a string?